# FreeIPA sign csr which can give out other certificates

Tags: openssl, pkcs#12, freeipa

How can I sign a csr with `CA:true` attribute using FreeIPA's CA private key?
Reason being, I want a remote site to give out its own certificate using this certificate.
Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Please follow Fraser's blog about just that topic: https://frasertweedale.github.io/blog-redhat/posts/2018-08-21-ipa-subordinate-ca.html